# HTML Option Tag with Value set as an Anchor

Tags: html, anchor, optional-parameters

I am updating some super legacy code and I am unsure how to make this HTML5 compatible.

```
<option value='<a href='http://localhost:8080/dm?id=&#037;&#037;SUBSCRIBER_ID_TAG&#037;&#037;'>View in a browser window</a>'>Display Message(HTML Version)</option>
```

I personally have never run across something like that so any help would be great.

Comment: Your example is invalid HTML in any flavour, what's the correct code? If this is the real code then it needs fixing before you make it "HTML5"

Comment: Well all I know is that it has bee in a platform for probably 8 years. I am looking at how to change it completely so that it still functions (which I also need to see how it functions lol) and make it HTML 5 compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to the server side code? I'm presuming that somehow this value is populating a page.. I'd recommend you just pass the URL for the value, and in your server side code (or even if it's rendering in JavaScript) build link. Moreover, I suspect this code is highly susceptible to XSS, since it apparently renders whatever HTML is passed along.

Comment: Looking at it further it appears that it is using the value to actually display it at another spot on the html page.

Comment: Same situation, whether that rendering is done server-side or client-side. So if it's just a document.write or similar, pre-build your <a> code, grabbing the URL from the <option> value, rather than outputting the value as an entire HTML block. This will help you get to HTML 5 conformation.